# R shiny tool tips with shinyBS

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

Hi I am adding tool tips to my shiny app with shinyBS.

```
bsTooltip("Input1", title = "text , placement = "bottom",
                                              trigger = "hover")
```

I am using google chrome, basically once I hover over `Input1` I see the tool tip 
. When I selected one choice in `Input1` and move on to the next choice menu, the tool tip wont disappear. Only if I refocus Input1 its disappears.

Here is a screenshot, to clear it up a bit.
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug that you should report to the package authors.